# Find all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^{2}+6xy+8y^{2}+3x+6y=2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^{2}+6xy+8y^{2}+3x+6y=2$.

Using a brute-force algorithm, it seems like that the only solutions are:
$$(0,-1)\\(3,-2)\\(3,-1)\\(6,-2)$$
But I can't manage to prove it. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: factor the left side as a polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^2 + (6y+3)x + 8y^2 + 6y - 2 = 0\implies \triangle_x = b^2-4ac = (6y+3)^2- 4(8y^2+6y-2) = k^2\implies 4y^2+12y+17-k^2=0\implies \triangle'_y=(b')^2-ac=(6)^2-4(17-k^2)=l^2\implies 36+4k^2=68+l^2\implies4k^2-l^2= 68-36= 32\implies (2k+l)(2k-l)=32$. Can you take it from here to solve for $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x,y$ .